# How do I resolve encryption error connecting to SQL Server from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, jtds

My objective is to use the migration tool in SQL Developer to migrate 2 SQL Server databases to Oracle. I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server database at a remote location using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.

I have installed jtds.1.3.0.jar per instructions, and get the SQL Server and Sybase tabs in the connection properties window.

I have entered the user, pw, hostname, port, and database name.  When I try to Retrieve Database, or connect, I get the error message:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.

The SQL Server DBA tells me her error logs contain the following error message:

> Encryption is required to connect to this server but the client library does not support encryption; the connection has been closed. Please upgrade your client library. [CLIENT: (my computer's IP address)] Error: 17835, Severity: 20, State: 1.

When I look at SQL Server documentation about this error message, it talks about certificates and SQL Server Connection Manager. Some relevant information to show that I've covered the basics:

1. Using the same connection parameters, I am able to connect to the SQL Server database using Toad for SQL Server.
2. Using the same connection parameters, a DBA set up an Oracle Transparent Gateway, and I can connect to the SQL Server database using the gateway and a database link. (As far as I know, neither of these methods required a certificate to connect.)

Both of these use ODBC; SQL Developer uses jdbc with TCP/IP.

The DBA assures me TCP/IP connection is turned on for the SQL Server databases.

I have gone into the XML file where SQL Developer stores the connection string.  It has the form `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sql-xxx-xxx.mw.nos.xxx.com:1433/my_db`, which looks correct. I have tweaked it by adding the instance name, but no difference. The database has a default instance name, anyway, so it shouldn't be necessary.

A co-worker has been able to connect to a local SQL Server database on the same machine where SQL Developer was running (both on his laptop).

As a workaround, I am also pursuing the possibility of installing SQL Server on a local workstation, and copying the databases there for processing, but I don't know if I can get approval. If you know another tool for migrating from SQL Server to Oracle, please also let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your connection string should have encrypt=true, please take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption

Comment: Thank you, sepupic.  I'm going to have to use a workaround at this time due to time constraints, so I can't report success.  When I went out to the sourceforge website to get more information on the parameters involved, I also found this in the Bugs section: #759 issue with encrypted connection - SQL server 2012.  https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/759/

Comment: We have an offline capture mode where you can give scripts to be ran that will build the data model for the migration project.